# How do I multiply a user's text by an array item selected from a menu?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to write a gross pay calculator, and can't quite get the coding right to multiply the user entered number by the selected pay rate.

Everything I try based off tweaking other project's code to fit my current project just returns errors.

```
Private strCode(,) As String = {{“P23”, “10.5”},
                                    {“P56”, “12.5”},
                                    {“F45”, “14.25”},
                                    {“F68”, “15.75”},
                                    {“F96”, “17.65”}}
Private Sub txtHours_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtHours.KeyPress
        ' Accept only numbers, the period, and the Backspace key.

        If (e.KeyChar < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar > "9") AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "." AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub BtnCal_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
        Const V As strCodes(,)(,)
        Dim txtHours As Decimal = txtHours.text
        lblGross.Text = {{txtHours.Text} * {lstCodes.SelectedIndex}}
   End Sub
```

Whether I declare the txtHours as double, decimal, it always returns the error that it can't be converted. The bottom portion of the code is non-working, but is essentially what I need to happen with this code.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. This is a 2 part process. First for the current project - In Solution Explorer double click My Project. Choose Compile on the left. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. Second for future projects - Go to the Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults. In the Option Strict drop-down select ON. This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect to see something more like:

```
Private Sub BtnCal_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCalc.Click
    If lstCodes.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        Dim quantity, rate As Double
        If Double.TryParse(txtHours.Text, quantity) AndAlso Double.TryParse(lstCodes.SelectedItem, rate) Then
            Dim price As Double = quantity * rate
            lblGross.Text = price
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Quantity and/or Rate!")
        End If
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("No Rate Selected!")
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a great step in the right direction. It actually does something when I enter a number instead of just staring back at me. Now I need to get it to read the selected.index from the Array.

Comment: Well, you'll have to explain better how that's supposed to work.  I have no idea what you're after based on the code you posted....

Answer (score 0):

I created a structure to hold your data. A list of the type of structure then can keep the data and a List(Of T) can be bound to a list box. The display and value members are set to the properties of the structure. When an item is selected in the list box we can get the .SelectedValue and use it in the calculation.

```
Public Structure PayRate
    Public Property RateClass As String
    Public Property PayRate As Decimal
    Public Sub New(rClass As String, pRate As Decimal)
        RateClass = rClass
        PayRate = pRate
    End Sub
End Structure

Private PayRates As New List(Of PayRate)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PayRates.Add(New PayRate(“P56”, 12.5D))
    PayRates.Add(New PayRate(“F45”, 14.25D))
    PayRates.Add(New PayRate(“F68”, 15.75D))
    PayRates.Add(New PayRate(“F96”, 17.65D))
    ListBox1.DataSource = PayRates
    ListBox1.DisplayMember = "RateClass"
    ListBox1.ValueMember = "PayRate"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Hours As Decimal
    If Decimal.TryParse(TextBox1.Text, Hours) Then
        Label1.Text = (Hours * CDec(ListBox1.SelectedValue)).ToString("000.00")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid number in Hours box.")
    End If
End Sub
```